# How to redirect URL without port number to tomcat webserver

Tags: tomcat

I am using tomcat version 7 and have hosted one resource file in `webapp`. Right now, I am accessing my resource file by typing the URL `http://dcdvdvdsv.com:8080/resourcefilename`.

I have mapped my IP in my hosts file.

I want to get rid of the port number inside the URL. How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whenever you enter a URL without a port, it defaults to port 80, the standard http port.

[Change your Tomcat's listening port](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/) from `8080` to `80`, and you'll be done.